# Docker container keeps quitting

Tags: docker

Contents of Dockerfile:

```
FROM scardon/ruby-node-alpine:latest

WORKDIR /opt
COPY ./docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/

RUN apk update \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build_deps \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .run_deps python make \
  && gem install slim \
  && npm i -g gulp-cli gulp \
  && apk del .build_deps \
  && chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 3000
VOLUME [ "/opt" ]

CMD ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Contents of docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

exec npm i
exec npm run start
```

When i try to run the container with foreground mode:

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 -v ~/Sites/app:/opt imagename
```

It fires `npm i` command and exit. How to keep `npm run start` in a background, so it will be running all the time.

**UPDATED for Patok:**

```
exec node /var/www/project/backend/server.js > /var/log/node-server.log &
exec /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
exec tail -f /var/log/nginx/project.error.log & tail -f /var/log/node-server.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using multiple `exec` statements in script isn't possible, because it replaces current process by command running after `exec`. You could possibly use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

npm i
exec npm run start
```

or run `npm i` outside of this shell script (ie. directly in your Dockerfile's RUN directive).

Comment: i have a project, where's triple `exec` in a shell script (cmd). How do they work? Also i cant use `npm i` in a dockerfile's RUN, because i mount volume on a `docker run` command.

Comment: If you have multiple `exec` statements in your file, only first one command after `exec` is started, another ones are ignored. you can of course have multiple `exec` statements when you use proper branching with `if / elif / else` statements, but only one at a time is started depending on arguments or variables passed or any other external data being processed. because `exec` statement replaces script process itself, the script is not being processed anymore after the first command. try testing it in shell when you modify your script - instead of npm commands use `exec test1` and `exec test2`

Comment: You mean in my example, only first 2 `exec`'s are fired?

Comment: not only 2... only one is fired - the first one. Again - when you have script with multiple subsequent `exec` commands, then only FIRST ONE is run and replaces shell (`sh` in your script)... at that point no one of following `exec` will be started even the first `exec` command already ends its processing.

Comment: But the first one is going background, and second one is fired and the third in my case, because i can see the updated logs. Everything is fired in my example, but why? If you say only the first one would be fired?

Comment: oh... I miss & sigh after first `exec`; so yes, then also the second one is fired but because it's not backgrounded and doesn't run as a daemon, then the third one `exec` shouldn't be fired. maybe logs you see are output from nginx process not from tail commands... but you can check it from inside of container when you run shell in it with `docker exec -it <DOCKER-ID> sh` and then `ps aux | grep tail`. In any case using exec and backgrounding it with & is IMHO useless and you can run it without `exec` then. also it wont help you with running `npm i`, because you will want to wait till it ends.

Comment: so, conclusion is - the 3rd is not running, and i don't need more than 1 `exec` in a shell script, right?

Comment: yes, i guess so